# Store input value as a variable and then compare

Tags: jquery, node.js, input

I'm trying to compare 2 input values in a form to check if they are the same. Ultimately I want to prevent the default action when submitting but I put the validate button in for now just to more easily check if I'm capturing the right info.

```js
// store password inputs as variables
$('#password1').keyup(function() {
  var value1 = $("#password1").val();
  $("#password1").val(value1);
});

$('#password2').keyup(function() {
  var value2 = $("#password2").val();
  $("#password2").val(value2);
});

//  check if passwords match

$('#validate').on('submit', function() {
  if (value1 = value2) {
    alert("Yes they match")
  } else {
    alert("Passwords do not match")
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div class="form-group">
      <i class="fa fa-key" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <label for="password1">Password</label>
      <input id="password1" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter password" name="password1">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <i class="fa fa-key" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <label for="password2">Confirm password</label>
      <input id="password2" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter password" name="password">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <i class="fa fa-picture-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <label for="img">Image</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter image URL" name="image">
    </div>
    <button id="submit-login" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Signup</button>
  </form>
</div>
<button id="validate">Validate</button>
```

However it is not working. I tried adding a console.log into the code where I am trying to capture the inputs and it is indeed storing the logs but it doesn't seem to be storing the final value which I think may be causing the  issue here.

Comment: Define `value1` and `value2` variables outside click handler and `value1 === value2`

Comment: just to add to this, the error log appearing in the console when I click on the validate button confirms that value2 is not defined, so clearly I am not storing the variables correctly.

Comment: is that not what I'm doing with var value2 = $("#password2").val();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `value1` and `value2` out of the keyup functions, then they can be access from your validate

```
var value1 = "";
var value2 = "";
// store password inputs as variables
$('#password1').keyup(function() {
```

```js
var value1 = "";
var value2 = "";
// store password inputs as variables
$('#password1').keyup(function() {
  value1 = $("#password1").val();
  $("#password1").val(value1);
});

$('#password2').keyup(function() {
  value2 = $("#password2").val();
  $("#password2").val(value2);
});

//  check if passwords match

$('#validate').on('click', function() {
  if (value1 == value2 && value1.length > 0 && value2.length > 0) {
    alert("Yes they match")
  } else {
    alert("Passwords do not match")
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <i class="fa fa-key" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <label for="password1">Password</label>
  <input id="password1" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter password" name="password1">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <i class="fa fa-key" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <label for="password2">Confirm password</label>
  <input id="password2" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter password" name="password">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <i class="fa fa-picture-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <label for="img">Image</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter image URL" name="image">
</div>
<button id="submit-login" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Signup</button>
</form>
</div>
<button id="validate">Validate</button>
```

Comment: @Satpal Thanks for pointing it out, missed that he only used 1 `=`

Comment: thanks guys. Just briefly tried and the variables are indeed now accessible  which is great. I am not getting some slightly odd behaviour inasmuch as I can't type properly in the input box - it deletes every character I enter !! But I'll look at it properly later and hopefully figure that out.

Comment: @DaveB1 Hope it helps you, glad to help

Comment: @DaveB1, Go through Rory's answer that's a comprehensive solution

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is because the `value1` and `value2` variables are not in scope of the `submit` event handler. You can fix this, and simplify the logic, by just reading the `val()` of those elements within the `submit` event handler.

Also, you need to use `==` or `===` for comparison. `=` Is used to set values. The `#validate` element is a button, which will not raise the `submit` event - you need to place that on a `form` element, although presumably you would need to run this logic under both the `submit` of the `form` and `click` of the `#validate` button. With all that in mind, try this:

```js
$('form').on('submit', validate);
$('#validate').on('click', validate)
   
function validate(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // stop the submission in this demo

  if ($("#password1").val() == $("#password2").val()) {
    alert("Yes they match")
  } else {
    alert("Passwords do not match")
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <i class="fa fa-key" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <label for="password1">Password</label>
      <input id="password1" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter password" name="password1">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <i class="fa fa-key" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <label for="password2">Confirm password</label>
      <input id="password2" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter password" name="password">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <i class="fa fa-picture-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <label for="img">Image</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter image URL" name="image">
    </div>
    <button id="submit-login" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Signup</button>
  </form>
</div>
<button type="button" id="validate">Validate</button>
```

Comment: Comprehensive solution :)

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't need to set the variable for each input change
2. You need use `==` or `===` in `if` statement
3. You must use the `click` event for button `#validate` not the `submit`

--
Try my change! hope this can help!

```js
//  check if passwords match

$('#validate').on('click', function() {
 var value1 = $("#password1").val(),
    value2 = $("#password2").val();
  if (value1 == value2) {
    alert("Yes they match")
  } else {
    alert("Passwords do not match")
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div class="form-group">
      <i class="fa fa-key" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <label for="password1">Password</label>
      <input id="password1" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter password" name="password1">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <i class="fa fa-key" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <label for="password2">Confirm password</label>
      <input id="password2" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter password" name="password">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <i class="fa fa-picture-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <label for="img">Image</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter image URL" name="image">
    </div>
    <button id="submit-login" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Signup</button>
  </form>
</div>
<button id="validate">Validate</button>
```

Comment: My pleasure! :)